# ASP TextBox value assigned in client side not appearing in postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, postback, viewstate

I'm fetching data from database using ajax and jquery to fill the textboxes with some values. The issue is whenever a post back happens all the data which was assigne by jquery gets lost. I've tried almost everything.

I've removed the ReadOnly="true" property from textboxes.

I don't want to use Hidden Fields because I've almost 20-25 text boxes in single page. Is there any another approach to do this.

**Jquery Code**

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Services/Customer.asmx/GetCustomerDetails',
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ branchCode: BranchCode, customerCode: CustomerCode }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (returnedData) {
                    debugger;
                    var data = returnedData.d;
                    $("#txt_CustName").val(data[0].customerName);
                    $("#txt_AddressCust").val(data[0].address1);
                    $("#txt_AddressCust1").val(data[0].address2);
                    $("#txt_CityCust").val(data[0].City);
                    $("#txt_PinCodeCust").val(data[0].pinCode);
                    $("#txt_EmailCust").val(data[0].email);
                    $("#txt_MobileCust").val(data[0].mobile);
                    $("#txt_ContactPersonCust").val(data[0].contactPerson);
                    $("#txt_GSTNCust").val(data[0].GSTN);
                    $("#hdn_CustomerGroup").val(data[0].customerGroup);
                }
```

Please suggest me any solution...

Comment: if you want to keep your data after postback , you need to keep them somewhere on your page (hidden fields , json,...). and it dosnot cost you a lot

Comment: Try to use Input control and use as like "Request.Form["name"]" in backend.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, but will you please clarify it more

Comment: Ok fine. let me explain as answer.

Comment: yes please......

Comment: may be update panel can help, as data gets lost after postback.

Answer (score 0):

The value will be reset on each postback, when it is set from the client side.

Below is the way you can do something like,

**.ASPX**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#traveller_phone").val("9898948484");
});

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="traveller_phone" id="traveller_phone" />
<asp:Button ID="ClickMe" Text="click me" runat="server" OnClick="ClickMe_Click" />
```

**C#:**

```
protected void ClickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string phone = Request.Form["traveller_phone"];
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it did n't worked for me ...The value gets lost during postback

Comment: I should be work. I have updated my code with full description. Try to create new page and implement as above sample.

Comment: Sir, I've tried above code but I don't know why It's not working

Answer (score 0):

asp.net textbox control use attribute **ClientIDMode="Static"** .

Solved your problem try this.

Answer (score 0):

try below code.

.aspx

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txt_name").val("Cory");
        });

    </script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelLossHistory" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" runat="server" name="txt_name" id="txt_name" />                   
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Submit"  OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2" Text="DummyPostback"  />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>

</body>
```

C#:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string txtName = Request.Form["txt_name"];
    }
```

There are two buttons, one for submitting and second one for dummy postback hit.
Now, the value will not be lost if you click on "dummy" button and if you modify the name and click on "submit" you will get the modified name. I hope this helps.